# Set Data Type for Model ID - Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, long-integer, type-conversion

Is it possible for me set the **data type for model ID**, because my server sends a ID which is nearly a **long data type**, **which gets truncated to nearest value.**

Example : ID **2143531000000220011** gets truncated to **2143531000000220200**

Comment: [old but relevant](http://www.2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do arithmetic calculations with the model id, u can store it as a string.